# Framework or toolkit to implement RNN-transducer

Tags: speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network, speech-to-text, end-to-end

I'm studying the end-to-end architecture for automatic speech recognition systems.

RNN transducer (RNN-T) is one of the popular end-to-end methods, but it is so difficult to train.

Therefore I'm looking for a framework or a toolkit that can help me to easily implement the baseline model and then make modifications as I wish.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I'm currently using [ESPnet toolkit](https://github.com/espnet/espnet) which mainly focuses on end-to-end speech recognition and end-to-end text-to-speech.